# How to change radio button checkability state through :checked or :unchecked properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

as shown in the below posted code,i have tow `radio-buttons`, initially both of them are unchecked. the first one,when checked, the log message in `change_()` prints male. the second one when checked the log message in `change_()` prints female.
i would like to inquire about the following please:

1-how to change the checkability state of a `radio-button` through `:unchecked` property? in other words, when the `radio-button` is unchecked,i tried to change the value of `check1` for example to be `male`,`female` or any literal value else, however, that
did not trigger any change in the checkability state of the `radio-button`
i want to be able change the checkability state of a `radio-button` through the `:unchecked` property. is that possible?

2-if the answer to the latter point is "not possible", then what is the purpose of `:unchecked` and `checked` properties please?is it just to set an initial check state to the radio-button?

3- as the `radio-buttons` are initilaly unchecked, when I have them checked, that did not cause the interpolation values of either `check1` or `check2` displayed. i expected when the `radio-button` switches from unchecked to check state,consequently the interpolated
text between `{{}}` to change as well but that does not happen

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
<input type="radio" :unchecked="check1" @change="(event)=>change_(event)" :value="male" />
<input type="radio" :unchecked="check2" @change="(event)=>change_(event)" :value="female" />
<div>selected radio1: {{ check1 }}</div>
<div>selected radio2: {{ check2 }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
const check1 = ref('')
const check2 = ref('')
const male = ref('male')
const female = ref('female')

function change(params) {
  console.log("change_:",params.target.value);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the check ability state of a radio button using the :checked and :unchecked properties, you need to make the following modifications to your code:

Update the radio buttons'
checked and unchecked properties to bind them to the check1 and check2 variables, respectively:

Update the change_ function to update the check1 and check2 variables based on the selected radio button:

```vuejs
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <input type="radio" :checked="check1" @change="(event) => change_(event, 1)" :value="male" />
  <input type="radio" :checked="check2" @change="(event) => change_(event, 2)" :value="female" />
  <div>selected radio1: {{ check1 }}</div>
  <div>selected radio2: {{ check2 }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
const check1 = ref('');
const check2 = ref('');
const male = ref('male');
const female = ref('female');

function change_(event, option) {
  if (option === 1) {
    check1.value = event.target.value;
  } else if (option === 2) {
    check2.value = event.target.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: would you please tell me, since `check1.value = 'xxx'|'male'|'female'"  will not affect the check-ability of the radio-button, what is its use then please?